# Swap the constant of td using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to swap the content of two td's with each other by clicking on move up button.
I mean I want to swap content between the 2nd td and 3rd td.

I got that done but I am facing little problem in that i.e. "the swapped td's are not toggling the class that shows the current td is clicked or not after the swapping."

I am using this code for swapping the content of td's as below

```
var currentTr = $("#selectedTab td.backgroundcolor").parent();

var previousTr = currentTr.prev();

var temp = currentTr.html();

$(currentTr).html(previousTr.html());

$(previousTr).html(temp);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML manipulation in the DOM can be destructive. You should instead move the DOM nodes themselves.

```
var currentTr = $("#selectedTab td.backgroundcolor").parent();
var previousTr = currentTr.prev();

var temp = currentTr.contents().detach();

currentTr.append(previousTr.contents());

previousTr.append(temp);
```

This way you're not serializing, destroying and rebuilding all the nodes. You're just moving them.

Comment: if i need to swap multiple tds @squint

Comment: You'd need to write appropriate code to move the elements. Totally depends on the situation.